# Unable to find AppLovin SDK key. Please add meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="YOUR_SDK_KEY_HERE" into AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, sdk, applovin

**Hello everyone today I was busy with camera actions just applied rutin camera action on my application and apploving sdk key error actualy application is working but I need to know why I have this this warming on my android monitor**

**1. Here is my class where I start action and putExtra into intend**

```
public class CameraActionFragment extends Fragment 
{

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_IMG = 2;// for image

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO = 1;// for video

    public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;

    Button btn_frag_camera_image;

    Button btn_frag_camera;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_action_3, container, false);
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_action_3, container, false);
        btn_frag_camera_image = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_frag_camera_image);
        btn_frag_camera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_frag_camera);

        // Image Action
        btn_frag_camera_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello From Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intenImatToSec = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intenImatToSec, REQUEST_CODE_IMG);

            }
        });

        // Camera Action
        btn_frag_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intenImatToSec = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intenImatToSec, REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO);
                //intenImatToSec.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                //intenImatToSec.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello From Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMG) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                Intent intentBitMap = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class);
                // aldıgımız imagi burda yonlendirdiğimiz sınıfa iletiyoruz
                ByteArrayOutputStream _bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, _bs);
                intentBitMap.putExtra("byteArray", _bs.toByteArray());
                startActivity(intentBitMap);

            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO) {
                Uri videoUrl = data.getData();
                Intent intenToDisplayVideo = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayVideo.class);
                intenToDisplayVideo.putExtra("videoUri", videoUrl.toString());
                startActivity(intenToDisplayVideo);
            }
        }
    } }
```

**1. And I play my video here**

```
public class DisplayVideo extends Activity 
{
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO = 100;

    VideoView videoView;

    Button btn_cancel;

    Button btn_send_cahallenge;

    Button btn_image_play;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_video_activity);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview_display_video_actvity);
        btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_display_image_cancel);
        btn_send_cahallenge = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_display_image_send_cahallenge);
        btn_image_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_display_image_play);

        // CameraActionFragmentten gelen uri
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("videoUri"));
        videoView.setVideoURI(myUri);

        btn_image_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();
                editor.putInt("frag_no", 2);
                editor.commit();

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUrl = data.getData();
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUrl);
            //videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getApplicationContext()));
            //videoView.requestFocus();

        }


    }


}
```

**3. Cant find some usefull guide about AppLovin SDK key. Lately I
    defined facebook sdk key and everything was good and after camera
    actions ı have this problem**

**Error is**

```
 E/AppLovinSdk: Unable to find AppLovin SDK key. Please add     meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="YOUR_SDK_KEY_HERE" into AndroidManifest.xml.
07-29 16:24:26.390 12911-12911/? E/AppLovinSdk: Called with an invalid SDK key from: java.lang.Throwable: 
                                                    at com.applovin.impl.sdk.AppLovinSdkImpl.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk.b(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk.c(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk.b(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.qihoo.security.SecurityApplication.onCreate(360Security:263)
                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4806)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 4):

you have an invalid SDK key you need to setup AppLovin correctly

please try to add:

`<meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" 
            android:value="YOUR_SDK_KEY_HERE"/>`

to your `AndroidManifest` file inside `application` tag.

Comment: İnside the  android:value="YOUR_SDK_KEY_HERE" shouldnt be any kind of key ? I found this link but still complicated http://www.vmax.com/2016/03/16/applovin-integration-using-android-sdk

Comment: you have an `invalid SDK key` you need to setup AppLovin correctly.. this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link to find AppLovin SDK Key

[Click Here](https://dash.applovin.com/account#keys) To open AppLovin's Key Window
[image]